# Error while consuming webservice

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

But it does not create my new record in my crm.

> **Error:** Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://103.229.5.53:8201/DynamicsAx/Services/ACX_CaseTab leQ. The
>   connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0658227. TCP
>   erro r code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not pr operly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   103.229.5.53:8201.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk;
using System.ServiceModel.Discovery;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Program test = new Program();
                ClientCredentials cc = new ClientCredentials();
                cc.UserName.UserName = "";
                cc.UserName.Password = "";
                OrganizationServiceProxy service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(""), null, cc, null);
                string caseid = ""; string casetype = "";
                try
                {
                    QueryExpression query1 = new QueryExpression
                    {
                        EntityName = "e011_cases",
                        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("e011_caseid", "e011_casetype", "e011_casesid"),
                        Criteria = new FilterExpression()
                        {
                            FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                            Conditions = {
                                            new ConditionExpression
                                            {
                                                AttributeName ="e011_caseid",
                                                Operator=ConditionOperator.Equal,
                                                Values ={"CRM00000098"}
                                            },
                                        }
                        }
                    };

                    EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(query1);

                    if(ec.Entities[0].Contains("e011_caseid"))
                    {
                        caseid = ec.Entities[0].Attributes["e011_caseid"].ToString();
                    }
                    if(ec.Entities[0].Contains("e011_casetype"))
                    {
                        EntityReference er = (EntityReference)ec.Entities[0].Attributes["e011_casetype"];
                        casetype = er.Name.ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); Console.ReadKey();
                }

                ACX_CaseTableQ.ACX_CaseTableQServiceClient Proxy = new ACX_CaseTableQ.ACX_CaseTableQServiceClient();
                ACX_CaseTableQ.CallContext cnx = new ACX_CaseTableQ.CallContext();
                cnx.Company = "1100";
                Proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "";
                Proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "";
                Proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "";
                ACX_CaseTableQ.AxdACX_CaseTableQ ObjCasetableQ = new ACX_CaseTableQ.AxdACX_CaseTableQ(); string objcase =
                Convert.ToString(ObjCasetableQ.Acx_CaseTable_1);
                ACX_CaseTableQ.AxdEntity_Acx_CaseTable_1 objAxd = new ACX_CaseTableQ.AxdEntity_Acx_CaseTable_1();
                string zipcode = objAxd.Zipcode;
                string sate = objAxd.State;
                objAxd.CaseID = caseid;
                objAxd.CaseCategoryId = casetype; ObjCasetableQ.Acx_CaseTable_1 = new ACX_CaseTableQ.AxdEntity_Acx_CaseTable_1[1] { objAxd };
                ACX_CaseTableQ.EntityKey[] ReturnKey = Proxy.create(cnx, ObjCasetableQ);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error you are facing, to get quick attention to your problem.

Comment: Could not connect to net.tcp://103.229.5.53:8201/DynamicsAx/Services/ACX_CaseTab
leQ. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0658227. TCP erro
r code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not pr
operly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond 103.229.5.53:8201.

Comment: Even i ran it after turning off mmy firewall but still it does not work sir.

Comment: Why did you mess up your code again? Keep it in proper code formatting.

Comment: Refer [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting/editing your question next time.

Comment: k, i will sir. Do you have any idea what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Error means you cannot reach AX, nothing wrong with CRM here

Comment: Right!!, i found the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem can be related with CRM Online unavailability to connect with URL that contains IP address. This is system restriction. Try to use domain name instead of IP